# Issue with recursion while Permutations of a String

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to generate all capital permutations of a string.

For example:

> capitalPermutations(word) - Given a string of letters, return all the
>   possible combinations of lower and uppercase letters of that word.
>
> Example: 'abc'
>
> Ouput: ['abc' 'Abc' 'aBc' 'ABc' 'abC' 'AbC' 'aBC' 'ABC']
>
> Implement this in both iterative and recursive way.

This is my attempt:

```js
function capitalPermutations(word) {
  const res = new Set();
  
  // Push the actual word first.
  res.add(word);
  
  helper(word, res, '');
  
  return res;
  
  function helper(word, res, str='') {
    
    if(str.length === word.length) return;
    
    const len = word.length;
    res.add(word);
    
    // Capitalization
    for(let i=0; i< word.length; i++) {
      const substr = word.substring(0, i+1); // a, ab, abc
      str += substr; // str === "ABC" | len = 3
      const upper = str.toUpperCase(); // A, AB, ABC
      const remaining = `${upper}${word.substring(i, len)}`; // Abc , ABc, 
      helper(remaining, res, str);
    }
  }

}
var testWord1 = "abc"
console.log(capitalPermutations(testWord1))
```

**Issue:**
It's going into infinite recursion. Even though I have a breaking condition. Would really appreciate if someone can correct where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @kmgt There's nothing wrong with it, that's what recursion is actually good for - it's not easily achievable with iteration.

Comment: The assignment is confusing. This actually has nothing to do with permutations, which are about ordering.

Comment: "*I would really appreciate if someone can correct where I'm going wrong*" - could you please try to explain where you're going at all? I don't get your approach at all. Why are you iterating over the word length, and getting all prefixes from it? Why do you do `str += substr`? In your base case, did you mean to compare to the original `word`s length (the one passed to `capitalPermutations`), or to the `word` that's getting passed in the recursive call? And why do you add the `word` to the `res`ult in each recursion step, not only once at the end?

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the comment. I used `str` to just keep track of how many strings I'm processing. I understand my code is confusing (just trying to learn!) appreciate your help and all your comments.  In my base case, I was hoping to compare to my original word length (not the one that's getting passed) my bad!

Comment: Wouldn't generating all permutations produce strings such as `cab`, `bac`, etc.? Isn't this assignment only about generating all the different variations of casing?

Comment: @customcommander yes correct. only different variations of casing not all the permutations.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a recursive function which takes the collected letters of the last visited indices and check if the collected letter string has the same length as the given string. Then push the string to the result set.

The key is a double call of the recursion with a lower case letter and an upper case letter.

```js
function capitalPermutations(word) {
    function iter(temp = '') {
        if (temp.length === word.length) {
            result.push(temp);
            return;
        }
        iter(temp + word[temp.length].toLowerCase());
        iter(temp + word[temp.length].toUpperCase());
    }

    var result = [];
    iter();
    return result;
}

console.log(capitalPermutations('abc'));
```

The same with an iterative approach

```js
function capitalPermutations(word) {
    var result = [''],
        temp,
        i, j, upper, lower;

    for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        temp = result;
        result = [];
        lower = word[i].toLowerCase();
        upper = word[i].toUpperCase();
        for (j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
            result.push(temp[j] + lower, temp[j] + upper);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(capitalPermutations('abc'));
```

Comment: thank you. Soo clean!

If I were to do this iteratively, how would I do it? I'm thinking of having two for Loops and doing substring in one of the loop?

Comment: This also works with "abcde", so it seems to be a good solution.

Comment: ^^ This is the reason why I love SO so much!

Comment: @TechnoCorner. for the iterative approach, you need two loops, one for the characters of the word and one for the part result. please see edit.

Comment: @customcommander it's a typo..let me fix the question. This is the right answer

Comment: @customcommander, it takes all characters regardless of repetition. if that is not wanted, you could add something to get only unique characters.

Answer (score 2):

Traverse the string like a binary tree

```js
const permute = (str, prefix='') => {
  const idx = prefix.length
  if (idx===str.length)
    return [prefix]

  const lower = str[idx].toLowerCase()
  const upper = str[idx].toUpperCase()

  return [...permute(str, prefix + lower), ...permute(str, prefix + upper)]
}

console.log(permute('abc'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one with flatMap:

```js
function f(str){
  return str ? f(str.slice(1)).flatMap(sfx =>
    [str[0].toLowerCase() + sfx, str[0].toUpperCase() + sfx]) : [""]
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f("abc")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterative:

```js
function f(str){
  let res = [""]
  for (let c of str)
    res = res.flatMap(pfx =>
      [pfx + c.toUpperCase(), pfx + c.toLowerCase()])
  return res
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f("abc")))
```